# How does HodgeDual work?

Tags: implementation-details, tensors

The Hodge dual of a $p$-form is explicitly metric dependent, but the function `HodgeDual[]` doesn't seem to ask for the metric as an argument. How does that work? Does it mean that `HodgeDual[]` can only do the computation in Euclidean space?

Comment: Yes, currently HodgeDual assumes the metric is Euclidean.